# Novice SQL Update Question

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Revised Query.. the [Id] column is unique to all records.. the query should return the correct value for CorEURUSD to both Symbol = EURUSD and Symbol  = GBPUSD where the [Time] = [Time] values.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tck2](
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Symbol] [varchar](35) NULL,
[Time] [datetime] NULL,
[CorEURUSD] [decimal](14, 10) NULL,
[CorEURUSD2] [decimal](14, 10) NULL
  ) ON [PRIMARY]


 INSERT [VT7STAB1].[dbo].[Tck2] ([Symbol],[Time],[CorEURUSD],[CorEURUSD2]) VALUES('EUR/USD', '2011-07-01 12:04:28.000', 0.8229, 0.6488)
 INSERT [VT7STAB1].[dbo].[Tck2] ([Symbol],[Time],[CorEURUSD],[CorEURUSD2]) VALUES('EUR/USD', '2011-07-01 12:26:17.000', 0.9427, 0.6558)
 INSERT [VT7STAB1].[dbo].[Tck2] ([Symbol],[Time],[CorEURUSD],[CorEURUSD2]) VALUES('EUR/USD', '2011-07-01 12:58:34.000', 0.7713, 0.5267)
 INSERT [VT7STAB1].[dbo].[Tck2] ([Symbol],[Time],[CorEURUSD],[CorEURUSD2]) VALUES('GBP/USD', '2011-07-01 12:04:28.000', 0, 0)
 INSERT [VT7STAB1].[dbo].[Tck2] ([Symbol],[Time],[CorEURUSD],[CorEURUSD2]) VALUES('GBP/USD', '2011-07-01 12:26:17.000', 0, 0)
 INSERT [VT7STAB1].[dbo].[Tck2] ([Symbol],[Time],[CorEURUSD],[CorEURUSD2]) VALUES('GBP/USD', '2011-07-01 12:58:34.000', 0, 0)
```

Running the following query in an attempt to copy the CorEURUSD column from Symbol - 'EUR/USD' into the resulting CorEURUSD column for Symbol = 'GBP/USD

```
update Tck2
set CorEURUSD = (
     select CorEURUSD
     from Tck2 T 
     where Symbol = 'EUR/USD')
 where Symbol = 'GBP/USD'
```

gave this error
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

and when I used this revision..

```
update Tck2
set CorEURUSD = (
     select CorEURUSD
     from Tck2 T 
     where Symbol = 'EUR/USD')
 where Symbol = 'GBP/USD'
 and T.[Time] = [Time]
```

It throws this error.

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "T.Time" could not be bound.

I hope that is better, sorry for the 'mass-confusion'  please revise answers to match the above query and table which should be correct.

Comment: I believe that a simple INNER JOIN with multiple SELECT will work I just don't have enough SQL experience to do it

Comment: could you please explain more? I don't understand what you are trying to do. your condition ` T.[id] = [id]` (which is always true but I understand that you meant [id] column of the table being updated) results same row of the table. so that row's  [Symbol] can either be 'GBP/USD' or  'EUR/USD'. so only if you fix the syntax no row will be updated. please provide more info.

Comment: I think you might have a typo in your example (unless you only have one value of [CorEURUSD] when symbol='GBP/USD').  You can't have a unique key on [id] and also have two entries in your table with the same ID and two different values for [Symbol].  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi, @jj @maziar, sorry for the confusion please see above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess based on loose specs and no sample data / desired results.

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.[CorEURUSD] = x.[CorEURUSD] 
    FROM dbo.TicksForex AS t
    INNER JOIN dbo.TicksForex AS x
    ON t.[id] = x.[id]
    WHERE 
        t.[Symbol] = 'GBP/USD'
        AND x.[Symbol] = 'EUR/USD';
```

**EDIT 2011-07-03** 
Based on revised specs. Is [Time] really going to be your key for this type of update? Sounds risky. Anyway, since [Time] was the only way I could determine to join two rows based on your narrative and sample data, here is what I assume you mean (and I can also assume you only want to update CorEURUSD and not CorEURUSD2):

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.[CorEURUSD] = x.[CorEURUSD]
    FROM dbo.Tck2 AS t
    INNER JOIN dbo.Tck2 AS x
    ON t.[Time] = x.[Time]
    WHERE t.Symbol = 'GBP/USD'
    AND x.Symbol = 'EUR/USD';
```

Really wasn't that much of a modification really, I merely changed the join condition.

Comment: I have revised the query and table above ... the [Time] column identified a column that matches symbol and coreurusd .. the [id] was not correct. see above..

Answer (score 3):

The error message is saying that your subquery:

```
SELECT [CorEURUSD] 
  FROM TicksForex T 
 WHERE [Symbol] = 'EUR/USD' 
   AND T.[id] = [id]
```

...is returning more than one value.  Can't store more than one value in a single column.  You could use an aggregate to get the highest of the values:

```
SELECT MAX([CorEURUSD])
  FROM TicksForex T 
 WHERE [Symbol] = 'EUR/USD' 
   AND T.[id] = [id]
```

...or the lowest:

```
SELECT MIN([CorEURUSD])
  FROM TicksForex T 
 WHERE [Symbol] = 'EUR/USD' 
   AND T.[id] = [id]
```

...but you didn't provide details for us to work with.

Comment: There is not more than one value in the column, any column

Comment: @CraigJSte: I'm inclined to believe the error, rather than you.  But none of us have access to your data to check -- only you can.  I assume it's a typo that your query doesn't have brackets/parenthesis around the subquery?

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. Missing parenthesis.
2. `T.[id] = [id]` condition does not make much sense, as it is equivalent to `id = id`, which is always true.

   The query below should work, with the assumption that `Symbol` is unique:

   ```
   update TicksForex 
   set [CorEURUSD] = (
           select CorEURUSD 
           from TicksForex 
           where Symbol = 'EUR/USD'
       )
   where Symbol = 'GBP/USD'
   ```
3. However, from what your error suggests `Symbol` is not unique.

   Possible ways to fix this:

   - remove the duplicates. I believe this is the best solution, but can't tell for sure based on the info from the question
   - take first value:

     ```
     update TicksForex 
     set CorEURUSD = (
         select top 1 CorEURUSD
         from TicksForex T 
         where Symbol = 'EUR/USD')
     where Symbol = 'GBP/USD'
     ```
   - take `min`, `max`, `avg`, etc value:

     ```
     update TicksForex 
     set CorEURUSD = (
         select max(CorEURUSD)
         from TicksForex T 
         where Symbol = 'EUR/USD')
     where Symbol = 'GBP/USD'
     ```

   Basically you either need to make sure there are no duplicates, or to specify which exactly duplicate row should be used as the source of `CorEURUSD` value.

---

The way I tested this:

1. Created table using your script.
2. Filled table with two lines:

   ```
   insert TicksForex
   values('GBP/USD', 10, 20, 100)

   insert TicksForex
   values('EUR/USD', 30, 40, 200)
   ```
3. Ran the query as is:

   ```
   update TicksForex 
   set CorEURUSD = 
       select CorEURUSD
       from TicksForex T 
       where Symbol = 'EUR/USD' and T.[id] = [id]
   where Symbol = 'GBP/USD'
   ```

   Error:

   ```
   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.
   ```
4. Added parenthesis and removed `and T.[id] = [id]`:

   ```
   update TicksForex 
   set CorEURUSD = (
       select CorEURUSD
       from TicksForex T 
       where Symbol = 'EUR/USD')
   where Symbol = 'GBP/USD'
   ```

   Worked.
5. Added duplicate row:

   ```
   insert TicksForex
   values('EUR/USD', 50, 60, 300)
   ```
6. Ran script again:

   Error:

   ```
   Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
   ```
7. Tried all 3 solutions from my answer above - worked.

**[EDIT]** After sample data is provided.

If the time is absolutely matching, you can do this:

```
update t1 
set CorEURUSD = t2.CorEURUSD, CorEURUSD2 = t2.CorEURUSD2
from Tck2 t1 
    join Tck2 t2 on
        t1.Time = t2.Time
where 
    t1.Symbol = 'GBP/USD' and
    t2.Symbol = 'EUR/USD'
```

If the time is not completely matching, you can do this:

```
;with 
cte1 as
(
    select *, row_number() over (order by Time) RowNumber
    from Tck2
    where Symbol = 'EUR/USD'
),
cte2 as
(
    select *, row_number() over (order by Time) RowNumber
    from Tck2
    where Symbol = 'GBP/USD'
)
update cte2
set CorEURUSD = cte1.CorEURUSD, CorEURUSD2 = cte1.CorEURUSD2
from cte1 
    join cte2 on
        cte1.RowNumber = cte2.RowNumber
```

Comment: I have included the revised table and the query above and it returned an error when I ran it see above.. thanks for your help

Comment: @CraigJSte - I thought that I provided the same query as you marked as an answer. However, it was one day earlier than the marked answer. Just curious, what was the reasoning on selecting that answer over mine?

Comment: I can't be sure but think that @Aarons answer was either sooner after the edits occurred or it was a lot simpler and easier to understand, obviously you put a lot more work and thought into it and deserve credit.. so anyway I can try to split the bounty..

Comment: @CraigJSte - you can see from edit history that I updated the answer at Jul 2 at 20:02, and the answer that you marked was updated at Jul 3 at 15:17. So the answer that you marked is older and less detailed, which made me wondering why you chose this answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need parenthesis around the subquery or you would have another error thrown:

```
UPDATE TicksForex 
   SET [CorEURUSD] = ( SELECT [CorEURUSD] 
                        FROM TicksForex T 
                       WHERE [Symbol] = 'EUR/USD' 
                     )
WHERE [Symbol] = 'GBP/USD' ;
```

Second, the error suggests that there are more than one rows with `[Symbol] = 'EUR/USD'`.
This query will show a number more than `1`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [TicksForex] 
WHERE [Symbol] = 'EUR/USD' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I got your question

here is your query:

```
update a
set a.[CorEURUSD] = b.[CorEURUSD]
from [dbo].[Tck2] as a
join [dbo].[Tck2] as b on a.[Time] = b.[Time]
where a.[Symbol] = 'GBP/USD' and b.[Symbol]= 'EUR/USD'
```